# How to get text to display centre of page on same line as a list

Tags: html, css, center, alignment

Please check my website out:

http://www.budgie.richardcmpage.com/index.php

I've tried all sorts and can't get the text to be right in the middle of the screen with the social icons just floating to the right:

Code -

```
<div class='social_icons'>          
         <span class="social_icons_user"> Not already a user? <a class="signup2" href="register.php">Sign up here!</a>  
            <ul class="social_icons_ul">
                <li><a href="http://facebook.com/Budgie.SocialDiscussion"><img src="Images/facebook.png" alt="Facebook" width="16" height="16"></a></li>        
                <li><a href="https://profiles.google.com/u/0/112265357246183728158"><img src="Images/google.png" alt="Google" width="16" height="16"></a></li>              <li><a href="http://twitter.com/Budgie_SD"><img src="Images/twitter.png" alt="Twitter" width="16" height="16"></a></li> 
            </ul>               
          </span> 

</div>
```

CSS

```
.social_icons{
    height:50px;
    width:800px;
    background-color:#10260F;
    font-size:12px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;      
    margin-top:10px;
    color:#FFF;
    background-color:red;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

.social_icons_user{     
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:black; 
}

.social_icons_ul{       
    float:right;
}

.social_icons_ul li{
    display:inline;     
}
```

Comment: Your page has 2 doctype, more than one html element and you're loading 5 times the same CSS file: you'd better validate your page before trying to debug anything else or you'll waste your time on debugging the wrong things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.social_icons_ul {
position: absolute;
right: 0px;
top: 0px;
}

.social_icons_user {
display: block;
text-align: center;
background-color: black;
position: relative;
}
```

## there you are dude

Comment: WAAAAA GENIUS!!! THANK YOU!! Could you just touch upon the position parts of the css?

Answer (score 1):

Hi is very simple you can define in your css

**Css code**

```
  .social_icons{
    height:50px;
    width:800px;
    background-color:#10260F;
    font-size:12px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;      
    margin-top:10px;
    color:#FFF;
    background-color:red;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

.social_icons_user{     
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:black;
}

.social_icons_ul{       
    float:right;
}

.social_icons_ul li{
    display:inline;     
}
```

**yout html code here**

```
<div class='social_icons'>          
         <span class="social_icons_user"> Not already a user? <a class="signup2" href="register.php">Sign up here!</a>  
            <ul class="social_icons_ul">
                <li><a href="http://facebook.com/Budgie.SocialDiscussion"><img src="Images/facebook.png" alt="Facebook" width="16" height="16"></a></li>        
                <li><a href="https://profiles.google.com/u/0/112265357246183728158"><img src="Images/google.png" alt="Google" width="16" height="16"></a></li>              <li><a href="http://twitter.com/Budgie_SD"><img src="Images/twitter.png" alt="Twitter" width="16" height="16"></a></li>
            </ul>               
          </span>

</div>
```

and now [live demo here you can check](http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/UygUx/)